# Is there a more efficient way to write VBA with relative cell reference calculations?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm working on automating components of an Excel sheet with VBA, and I'm curious if there's a more efficient way to fill in calculations with relative cell references. This takes a few seconds to calculate over ~1,000 rows. Is there a way to do this more efficiently?

Currently I'm doing something like this to calculate a cell value, based on the difference between two above cells:

```
For Each cell In rng
    ' get the current row
    current_row = cell.Row

    ' check if we're in the cell that needs the calculation
    If ActiveSheet.Range("A" & current_row) = "criteria" Then
        ' take the difference of the two above cells
        cell.Formula = "=OFFSET(" & cell.Address & ", -2, 0) - OFFSET(" & cell.Address & ", -1, 0)"
    End If

Next cell
```

Alternatively, we could just calculate in place:

```
cell.Value = cell.Offset(-2, 0) - cell.Offset(-1, 0)
```

But that doesn't seem to be any faster.

The Excel format I'm stuck with is a non-standard rectangular format that I can't change, so while I know a standard columnar format would remove this issue all together, I'm trying to work within the confines of the existing format.

Comment: Set `Application.Calculation` to manual then set it back to automatic when done - that will speed this up.  Optionally also set `ScreenUpdating` to False

Comment: @TimWilliams Huh, that's all it was. Thank you! I marked as a duplicate because now knowing what to google, I found an existing answer.